# How to set default template for button?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

I have this:

```
btn.Template = (ControlTemplate)this.FindResource("Temp1");
```

But I want to get back to the default template, how to do this? I've tried:

```
btn.Template = null

Button b = new Button();
btn.Template = b.Template;

ControlTemplate ct = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Button));
btn.Template = ct;
```

But the button doesn't appear.

Comment: What happens when you say "it doesn't work?"

Comment: Just button doesn't appear

Comment: You cannot move templates across controls, see my answer for cloning.

Comment: remove all that and use proper XAML.

Answer (score 0):

you need to clone the default template. Check this code for cloning.
https://siderite.dev/blog/cloning-wpf-controltemplate.html